# Create bootable usb with rufus on a pc with Bitlocker enabled

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, bootable-media, rufus

I want to create a w10 bootable usb from a pc with bitlocker enabled.
Everytime I plug an usb drive pc asks me if I want to encrypt the drive etc. 
When I have tried to create a bootable I receive the message "media is write protected" or something similar. Is there a way to create bootable usb with bitlocker enabled?
I've disabled via "regedit" the automatic encryption but it not works.

Comment: It's a different problem, in my case when the tool (i.e. rufus) unplug and plug again the usb drive it becomes "write protected"..

Comment: Say no to encryption when asked.

Comment: yep i did it and initially it works, as far I can understand at a certain momenti it "reboot" the usb and then it cannot write on it anymore.

Comment: @ManuelCastro You're overthinking it and you apparently don't know a few things you should for the task you intend. Just open disk management and remove the encrypted partition. If need be create a new FAT32 one. Rufus shouldn't care what 's in it anywe, as long it's not locked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, BitLocker protection is required for a computer to be able to write
data to a removable data drive. Removable data drives that are not
BitLocker-protected will be mounted as read-only.
Only if the drive is protected by BitLocker, it will be mounted with read and write
access permissions.

This policy may be disabled as follows:

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
- Navigate to:
  *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Removable Data Drives*
- Double-click to edit "Deny write access to removable drives not protected by BitLocker policy"
- Click Disable and OK.

This option should have been Off by default. If this is a work computer, where it is
set by the administrator, you may not be able to disable it.

An alternative way is by registry changes:

**Enabling read-write access**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"RDVDenyWriteAccess"=dword:00000000
```

**Disabling read-write access**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"RDVDenyWriteAccess"=dword:00000001
```

For a work computer:
This is possibly a breach in the security policy of your company.
Use at your own risk.